# Capturar texto entre comillas dentro de etiqueta

Tags: php, regex

Deseo hacer un match a todo texto entre comillas que se encuentre entre un par de etiquetas especificas, por ejemplo
Código:

```
codigo cualquiera 1

[begin]

 "hola" <--- match a este

 123

 hola "hola" <-- math a este otro

[end]
```

```
[otro]

  "hola" <--- a este no

[otro]
```

La expresion regular que deseo que me ayuden es aquella que puede capturar el texto `"hola"` (con comillas dobles) que estan dentro de la `[begin]` y `[begin]` pero no el `hola` que no esta entre comillas dobles.

Intenté con:

```
[begin](\s*|.*)|".*"(\s*|.*)*[end]
```

esto me captura todo el contenido entre `[begin]` y `[end]`, pero lo que busco es capturar cualquier texto que esta entre comillas dobles.

Comment: La idea es buscar cualquier texto entre comillas dentro de las etiquetas [begin] y [end], hubo un error en la formulacion de la pregunta, disculpas.

Comment: Hay varias familias de implementaciones, por ejemplo no funciona igual ruby, php o javascript en regex

Comment: En PHP: \[begin\](\s*|.*)|".*"(\s*|.*)*\[end\] esto me captura todo el contenido entre [begin] y [end], pero lo que busco es capturar cualquier texto que esta entre comillas dobles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texto entre comillas, dentro de `[begin]` y `[end]`

**Expresión regular:**

```
/(?:\G(?!\A)|\[begin])[^["]*(?:\[(?!end])[^["]*)*"([^"]*)"/
```

**Descripción:**

[image: Visualización de https://www.debuggex.com/]

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[begin])` - Coincide con el inicio de una etiqueta o retoma desde la posición justo luego de las últimas comillas que coincidieron.

  - Opción 1: `\G(?!\A)` - coincide con la posición final de la [última coincidencia](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) también coincide con el inicio del string, por eso usamos `(?!\A)`, que no esté seguido por la posición inicial del string, para evitarlo.
  - Opción 2: `\[begin]` - literal `[begin]`
- `[^["]*(?:\[(?!end])[^["]*)*` - Consume todos los caracteres hasta unas comillas o la etiqueta de `[end]`.

  - `[^["]*` - cualquier caracter que no sea `[` ni `"`.
  - `(?:\[(?!end])[^["]*)*` - seguido opcionalmente de un `[` que no forma parte de `[end]` y más caracteres para consumir con `[^["]*`, esto repetido 0 o más veces.

  Esta estructura es análoga a usar `.*?` pero es más eficiente. Para más detalles, ver [*Unrolling the loop*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).
- `"([^"]*)"` - Texto entre comillas, capturado por el [grupo](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) (paréntesis) para obtenerlo como un índice independiente en el array de resultados.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/BX9lUy/1/

---

**Código:**

```php
<?php
$texto = 'codigo cualquiera 1

[begin]

 "hola" <--- match a este

 123

 hola "hola" <-- math a este otro

 "chau!"

[end]
[otro]

  "hola" <--- a este no

[otro]';



//Aplicar el regex
$regex = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|\[begin])[^["]*(?:\[(?!end])[^["]*)*"([^"]*)"/';
preg_match_all($regex, $texto, $resultado);

//Imprimir resultados del primer grupo, que es un array dentro de $resultado[1]
echo join("\n", $resultado[1]);
```

**Resultado:**

```
hola
hola
chau!
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/6VEEUt